# Python: urllib3 errors where requests works

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

I have the following code

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
resp = http.request(
    "GET",
    "https://api.nhs.uk/medicines/aciclovir",
    headers={
        "subscription-key":"XXX"
    }
)
print(resp.data)
```

The response is:

```
You don't have permission to access "http://api.nhs.uk/medicines/aciclovir" on this server
```

Why has it gone to a `http://` address?

However when I use requests as below, it's a success

```
url = "https://api.nhs.uk/medicines/aciclovir"

payload={}
headers = {
  'subscription-key': 'XXX'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

This is the exact code that is being executed for the error to happen which yes, it does show a `http://` error

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

**urllib3**

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0 7777
Connection received on *** 50054
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ***:7777
Accept-Encoding: identity
subscription-key: xxx
User-Agent: python-urllib3/1.26.9
```

**requests**

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0 7777
Connection received on *** 50095
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ***:7777
User-Agent: python-requests/2.28.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
subscription-key: xxx
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted adequately represents the code you are executing? The error message says `http://...`, but in code you have `https://...`? How did that `http://...` get there?

Comment: Yeah - I have just copied and pasted what I have used. Why it's going to a `http://` addy is a mystery

Comment: I guess the message could have been created (erroneously) serverside. OK, diagnostics time: `nc -l 7777` in a terminal, then change URL in both snippets to `http://localhost:7777`. This should let you see if there is a difference in the requests.

Comment: This is an IIS box I don't have control over - woe is me - will see what I can do

Comment: I have done that now and added to the question

Comment: I just did the experiment, and there are slight differences but nothing that should matter: `User-Agent` and `Accept-Encoding` are different, `requests` version also supplies `Accept: */*` and `Connection: keep-alive`. None of this should matter, unless the server is coded to really hate one of the `urllib3`'s headers. So I'll ask a stupid question — are you sure the error is at the code you posted, and not at a similar code somewhere else?

Comment: If I put it in a standalone file. I get the same error with no other code in there

Comment: The next step is to try to imitate `requests` headers, then. See if you can construct the exact headers that `requests` sends in your `urllib3` code; if it works, you'll know the server is explicitly checking one of the headers and doesn't like what it sees, which you can then explicitly set. Once you know the problem is in the headers, you can change one by one to narrow down what exactly the server wants. If it doesn't work... it's gremlins.

Comment: I've changed the user agent and it works!!!

Comment: Great :) I typed a lot in the comments, you can type the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

With thanks from https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan the problem was that the server does not like the default user agent string supplied by urllib3

Changing it or even just breaking up the `python-urllib` string such as `pyXthon-urllib` makes it work

I have took this up with their support